# How does Autowire work when referring only to a base class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to extend existing code which auto-wires a number of components which share the same base class and are only referred to by their base class, ei:

```java
@Configuration
public class NavigationHotKeyBindConfigs {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(NavigationHotKeyBindConfigs.class);

    @Autowired
    private HotKeyConfig hotKeyConfig;

    @Autowired
    private ANavigation upNavigation;

    @Autowired
    private ANavigation downNavigation;

    @Autowired
    private ANavigation centerOnSelection;

    @Autowired
    private ANavigation handVerify;
```

```java
public abstract class ANavigation {
    @Autowired
    protected ScrollSchedulerConfigurer scrollSchedulerConfigurer;

    public abstract void execute(DetectionView DetectionView);
}
```

```java
@Component
public class DownNavigation extends ANavigation{

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DownNavigation.class);

    public void execute(DetectionView detectionView){
        logger.info(String.format("Received: Navigation key %s", ENavigationKey.DOWN.name()));
        scrollSchedulerConfigurer.stop();
        detectionView.selectNextDetection();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class UpNavigation extends ANavigation{

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(UpNavigation.class);

    public void execute(DetectionView detectionView){
        logger.info(String.format("Received: Navigation key %s", ENavigationKey.Up.name()));
        scrollSchedulerConfigurer.stop();
        detectionView.selectPrevDetection();
    }
}
```

I don't understand how spring is ever supposed to match up upNavigation/downNavigation with the UpNavigation/DownNavigation components respectively. Was this just bad design from the original author or is there a subtlety I'm missing?

This lack of understanding is also causing some issues as the centerOnSelection and handVerify objects end up NULL after autowiring though they follow the same pattern in every way I can see. Interestingly, this last behavior is different when run in the intellij IDE vs when run out of a .jar

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null`, if an `@Autowired` field/constructor/method cannot be fulfilled the application won't even start. So either it isn't `null` and you are looking at the proxy (no fields) instead of the actual implementation or you are creating instances of classes yourself or at least outside the scope of spring. For more details see [this blog](https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/)

Comment: It would appear my problem is that my HandVerify component depends on an autowired component which works elsewhere in my application but not here. If I comment out that member from my HandVerify class it is properly instantiated.

Comment: Again an autowired field cannot be `null` your application wouldn't even start. So you must be letting something out of your question that leads to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this ...

Let's say we have two beans which have the same base class or interface

```
@Component("fooFormatter")
public class FooFormatter implements Formatter {
 
    public String format() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

@Component("barFormatter")
public class BarFormatter implements Formatter {
 
    public String format() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

Then we inject them like this ...

```
public class FooService {
     
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fooFormatter")
    private Formatter formatter;
}
```

From the point of view of clarity and maintainability this seems to be the best solution

Comment: I like this approach better than magic variable names. Thanks!

Comment: Will test first! :)

Comment: @Techniquab Did you test and it worked ? If so, please feel free to accept and upvote, so its easier for others to find it and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` first looks at the type of the variable and then the name of the variable to match the correct bean. By default, the name of a class marked with `@Component` is its short name, e.g. `upNavigation` for the `UpNavigation` class.

```
@Autowired
private ANavigation upNavigation;
```

is the same as

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("upNavigation")
private ANavigation upNavigation;
```

And

```
@Component
public class UpNavigation
```

is the same as

```
@Component("upNavigation")
public class UpNavigation
```

Since the names match, Spring is able to find the corresponding bean.

Comment: I figured it had to do something like that, but my variable/class names fit the rules you mention and it is not working in the JARed version.